# Inserting a table with a picture in a header

Tags: tables, header-footer

I am trying to create a table inside a header in order to insert a picture and some text.
The reason being that I would like them to be aligned.
Unfortunately in the first page of the document I get the text inside the header and the footer does not appear. After the first page everything seems to work fine.

1. Am doing something wrong? (obviously)
2. Is there a more efficient way to do so?

Thank you

P.S.

I am including in my MWE all preamble commands in case mistake originates form there.

MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{report}
% Packages
\usepackage[paperwidth=210mm, paperheight=297mm]{geometry} % Paper Dimensions
\usepackage{ragged2e} % Left and Right alignment
\usepackage{afterpage} % Placing graphs directly after running page
\usepackage{lastpage} % Count total number of pages
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Headers and Footers
\usepackage{ucs} % Languages
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % Languages
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\newcommand{\en}{\selectlanguage{english}}
\newcommand{\gr}{\selectlanguage{greek}}
\usepackage{appendix} % Appendices
\usepackage{color} % Colored Fonts
\usepackage{graphicx} % Pictures
\usepackage{amsmath} % Mathematical Equations
\usepackage{array} % Tables
\usepackage{multirow} % Tables - Merging Columns
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % Tables
\usepackage{hyperref} % References
%
\geometry{a4paper, left=28mm, right=23mm, top=10mm, bottom=15mm}
%
\begin{document}
%
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt} % Footer Line
%
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{1}
%
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.16]{ex_logo.png}
\end{figure}
%
% Company Logo
\title{\textsc{\Huge \textcolor{blue}{\en TEX}}}
\gr \author{Εκδοσις 2.0}
\gr \date{\textsc{\today}}
\maketitle
\newpage


\begin{abstract}

\en
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur tortor arcu, consectetur quis ipsum id, tempor consequat ligula. Aenean vehicula velit erat, eu efficitur mi accumsan at. Sed et massa bibendum, fringilla mauris sit amet, gravida erat. Quisque volutpat purus vitae ex interdum scelerisque. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Praesent sed dignissim nisi. Ut nec scelerisque eros. Donec maximus ipsum a faucibus accumsan.

Ut eget laoreet metus. Donec pellentesque ligula nec nibh rutrum, vehicula posuere nunc aliquam. Sed dolor nibh, laoreet vel ligula finibus, lobortis porta ex. Sed vel vehicula leo. Nam vel nisi mollis, bibendum tellus ut, dapibus sapien. Duis non sem vel erat tincidunt tempor et quis nisl. Maecenas sit amet risus risus. Nunc vel nibh a felis venenatis commodo vitae eget massa. Nulla eros neque, dapibus eget mattis at, imperdiet non risus. Aliquam maximus turpis id eleifend luctus. Etiam id feugiat urna. Nam quam velit, volutpat id laoreet in, ultricies nec dolor.

Sed sed consectetur ligula. Nunc consequat auctor tellus, ut consequat elit sodales ac. Duis aliquet ut est eget gravida. Suspendisse maximus est ac odio interdum, vel blandit mauris pulvinar. Etiam vel luctus velit, sit amet luctus neque. Suspendisse finibus, erat eget tristique malesuada, felis nisl ultricies velit, ut tristique turpis mi non felis. Pellentesque quis ullamcorper purus. In quis dui ac lacus laoreet egestas sed eget sapien. Morbi eget interdum dui. Curabitur iaculis lacus sed nibh molestie, et feugiat orci gravida. Maecenas volutpat metus sed nulla auctor, in accumsan augue iaculis. Maecenas velit leo, vestibulum vitae risus nec, feugiat tempus orci. Mauris volutpat congue enim tempor consequat. Curabitur sed lacus vel libero cursus lacinia ut in purus.

Fusce rhoncus euismod fringilla. Aliquam volutpat et turpis feugiat euismod. Morbi quis sapien et enim egestas tempus. Duis quis ligula sem. Sed eleifend, ligula eget pulvinar iaculis, augue quam feugiat urna, sed aliquet arcu tortor ut magna. Quisque pulvinar sit amet dui id finibus. Curabitur a finibus ex, vel pulvinar quam. Cras feugiat viverra tincidunt. In euismod eu metus non blandit. Praesent ullamcorper dui in tellus bibendum, ac bibendum felis imperdiet. Phasellus eget sollicitudin mi. Curabitur augue risus, feugiat sit amet elit a, consequat imperdiet dui. Duis molestie tellus eros, vitae sagittis odio tristique sed. Sed tincidunt auctor augue eu egestas. Donec cursus felis eget viverra cursus. Nullam molestie nisl id sollicitudin dapibus.\\
\end{abstract}
\newpage
%
% Table of Contents
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
%
% Page Numbering Style
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
%
\voffset = -21mm
\topmargin= 0mm
\headheight= 4mm 
\headsep= 10mm
\textheight= 220mm
\footskip= 25mm
\textwidth = 155mm
% Chapters
\include{chap}
%
\end{document}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{\begin{tabular}{ll}
\multirow{6}{*}{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{ex_logo.png}} & \textcolor{blue}{\en TEX} \\
& \en A great site for \LaTeX enthusiasts\\
& \href{https://tex.stackexchange.com/}{\en https://tex.stackexchange.com/}, \en \href{mailto:info@tex.stackexchange.com/}{info@tex.stackexchange.com} \\
& \\
\end{tabular}}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{\en tex.stackexchange.com}
\rfoot{\gr Σελίδα \thepage \hspace{1pt} απο \en \pageref{LastPage}}

\section{\en Lorem}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur tortor arcu, consectetur quis ipsum id, tempor consequat ligula. Aenean vehicula velit erat, eu efficitur mi accumsan at. Sed et massa bibendum, fringilla mauris sit amet, gravida erat. Quisque volutpat purus vitae ex interdum scelerisque. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Praesent sed dignissim nisi. Ut nec scelerisque eros. Donec maximus ipsum a faucibus accumsan.

Ut eget laoreet metus. Donec pellentesque ligula nec nibh rutrum, vehicula posuere nunc aliquam. Sed dolor nibh, laoreet vel ligula finibus, lobortis porta ex. Sed vel vehicula leo. Nam vel nisi mollis, bibendum tellus ut, dapibus sapien. Duis non sem vel erat tincidunt tempor et quis nisl. Maecenas sit amet risus risus. Nunc vel nibh a felis venenatis commodo vitae eget massa. Nulla eros neque, dapibus eget mattis at, imperdiet non risus. Aliquam maximus turpis id eleifend luctus. Etiam id feugiat urna. Nam quam velit, volutpat id laoreet in, ultricies nec dolor.

Sed sed consectetur ligula. Nunc consequat auctor tellus, ut consequat elit sodales ac. Duis aliquet ut est eget gravida. Suspendisse maximus est ac odio interdum, vel blandit mauris pulvinar. Etiam vel luctus velit, sit amet luctus neque. Suspendisse finibus, erat eget tristique malesuada, felis nisl ultricies velit, ut tristique turpis mi non felis. Pellentesque quis ullamcorper purus. In quis dui ac lacus laoreet egestas sed eget sapien. Morbi eget interdum dui. Curabitur iaculis lacus sed nibh molestie, et feugiat orci gravida. Maecenas volutpat metus sed nulla auctor, in accumsan augue iaculis. Maecenas velit leo, vestibulum vitae risus nec, feugiat tempus orci. Mauris volutpat congue enim tempor consequat. Curabitur sed lacus vel libero cursus lacinia ut in purus.

\section{\en Second Subsection}
Fusce rhoncus euismod fringilla. Aliquam volutpat et turpis feugiat euismod. Morbi quis sapien et enim egestas tempus. Duis quis ligula sem. Sed eleifend, ligula eget pulvinar iaculis, augue quam feugiat urna, sed aliquet arcu tortor ut magna. Quisque pulvinar sit amet dui id finibus. Curabitur a finibus ex, vel pulvinar quam. Cras feugiat viverra tincidunt. In euismod eu metus non blandit. Praesent ullamcorper dui in tellus bibendum, ac bibendum felis imperdiet. Phasellus eget sollicitudin mi. Curabitur augue risus, feugiat sit amet elit a, consequat imperdiet dui. Duis molestie tellus eros, vitae sagittis odio tristique sed. Sed tincidunt auctor augue eu egestas. Donec cursus felis eget viverra cursus. Nullam molestie nisl id sollicitudin dapibus.

Duis id erat elementum, egestas nibh sed, convallis ex. Pellentesque scelerisque, nisi ut blandit cursus, lacus metus pharetra turpis, quis tempor sem est sed tortor. Phasellus vitae odio at elit gravida dapibus at vel metus. Cras ac fringilla sapien. Nunc at aliquet purus. Suspendisse et porttitor est. Curabitur scelerisque rutrum iaculis. Cras erat dui, cursus luctus lectus ut, consequat finibus arcu. Vivamus porttitor a risus vel sagittis.

In ac molestie mi. Nullam purus turpis, maximus et mi aliquam, scelerisque tincidunt lorem. Vestibulum facilisis dui nisi, quis fermentum erat pulvinar eu. Vestibulum id lacinia eros, volutpat dignissim odio. Duis id dictum libero, eu porttitor ex. Donec non placerat orci. Vestibulum quis diam dignissim, congue mi a, ultricies neque.

Integer ornare nunc risus, bibendum egestas ex scelerisque ac. Donec at felis ex. Donec et porta lorem. Donec quam sapien, consequat vitae est ultricies, porttitor rutrum elit. Aenean non dolor erat. Aenean gravida massa sed lectus gravida, quis tempor neque finibus. Cras lacus eros, dignissim quis consequat id, convallis et nisi. Nulla dolor nulla, auctor at luctus vel, laoreet id enim. Etiam tempus eget tellus quis dignissim. Pellentesque ac rhoncus diam, nec iaculis metus. Nam feugiat massa eget vulputate suscipit. Ut nec justo facilisis nisl sagittis malesuada. Pellentesque luctus blandit nisi, non sodales justo varius et.

Aliquam gravida pharetra arcu, congue tincidunt diam eleifend id. Aliquam at vestibulum enim. In efficitur dignissim justo, sed scelerisque tortor fringilla vel. Nam sit amet placerat dolor, sit amet euismod orci. Fusce tincidunt ornare elementum. Integer scelerisque rutrum quam, in feugiat ipsum aliquam sed. Sed eu dui tincidunt mi eleifend consectetur eu et augue.

\subsection{\en First Subsection}
Integer vel nisi risus. Donec fermentum metus sit amet hendrerit euismod. Donec non tempus massa. Aenean quis hendrerit lorem. Phasellus pharetra mattis augue in accumsan. Mauris non justo a ante viverra semper et ultrices justo. Duis vel turpis in elit euismod rutrum vel id lectus. Pellentesque molestie nisi at dolor fermentum porttitor. Curabitur tortor elit, molestie ut mattis consequat, viverra ultricies ligula. Fusce molestie sit amet magna rhoncus commodo. Sed lacinia, neque quis pharetra varius, ante ante ullamcorper lectus, quis lacinia magna nunc in enim. Nunc ipsum mauris, condimentum sed dui ac, interdum elementum diam. Fusce luctus sollicitudin metus a fermentum. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aenean nisi velit, sollicitudin ut libero in, dignissim consequat mi. In tellus ante, tincidunt vel vestibulum in, blandit eget urna.

Sed finibus placerat ex eget pellentesque. Nam venenatis consectetur massa, et scelerisque elit consectetur a. Nulla turpis est, pellentesque nec bibendum aliquam, porta non neque. Nullam mollis commodo est. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vivamus eget massa non augue aliquam scelerisque eget eget mauris. Aliquam in neque et dolor elementum imperdiet in eu sem. Mauris pharetra varius ante ac tempus. Nam et nulla non turpis iaculis egestas. Morbi eget fermentum nulla. Duis sem lectus, aliquet non consequat nec, facilisis at odio. Morbi ac mi mollis, porttitor enim in, luctus arcu. Sed tincidunt augue augue, aliquam molestie lorem hendrerit et.

\subsection{\en Second Subsection}
Suspendisse mi dui, tincidunt sed iaculis ac, elementum vel enim. Suspendisse et lorem nec lacus blandit posuere. Integer suscipit pulvinar metus. Fusce vel aliquam sem, ac eleifend odio. Morbi justo lectus, dapibus et urna vel, suscipit ultrices leo. Fusce mauris nisi, porta faucibus libero sed, venenatis cursus mi. Curabitur lectus felis, hendrerit eget ullamcorper et, gravida ut quam. Duis lacus dui, ornare at felis vel, iaculis posuere quam. Sed dignissim ut lacus bibendum hendrerit.

Suspendisse auctor, ligula sit amet dapibus consequat, turpis nulla mollis lorem, eget consectetur nibh metus a lectus. Ut et pharetra nulla, malesuada ornare purus. Ut vitae pulvinar mi. Integer nunc nulla, maximus in accumsan sit amet, tincidunt sed justo. Nunc arcu urna, dapibus et ornare id, mollis non leo. Morbi at lectus at velit convallis pretium et in augue. Curabitur porttitor rutrum odio, sit amet sagittis nibh. Etiam posuere mauris vel lobortis euismod. Praesent in malesuada eros. Nam sit amet tortor urna. Integer metus quam, aliquet sit amet leo sit amet, fringilla tincidunt leo.

Suspendisse iaculis arcu vitae rhoncus molestie. Etiam fringilla nunc enim, nec rhoncus massa pharetra at. Vivamus suscipit bibendum mauris eget viverra. Nam consectetur mauris quis tempus lobortis. Vestibulum quis lacinia enim. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Maecenas velit ex, aliquam a lacinia at, bibendum bibendum magna. Sed tristique id justo ullamcorper efficitur. Donec blandit ac purus hendrerit tempus. Nulla commodo bibendum bibendum. Phasellus bibendum mauris sit amet sapien pellentesque accumsan. Mauris vitae efficitur magna.

Cras vel metus non nisl iaculis auctor. Proin vel ultrices enim, eu dapibus nibh. Maecenas lacinia eget urna sed eleifend. Mauris ut dolor rutrum augue rhoncus facilisis ac ac felis. Duis vitae consectetur lacus, vitae ultrices ex. Curabitur vel lectus sapien. Duis eu eros est. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Suspendisse at cursus metus. Duis imperdiet metus elit, et congue nulla eleifend ut. Sed condimentum magna ut bibendum semper.

Pellentesque tempor leo viverra dolor ultrices, nec interdum enim vestibulum. Vestibulum molestie pretium pellentesque. Morbi vestibulum auctor rutrum. Sed commodo sapien dui, eget gravida nisi tempus consectetur. Cras at eleifend nisl. Nulla facilisi. Nullam iaculis posuere tincidunt. Vestibulum et quam quis odio pellentesque aliquam. Sed mattis ultricies elit id ornare.

Aliquam pretium laoreet finibus. Integer convallis fermentum elit, at egestas ex iaculis vitae. Mauris vel sagittis diam. Nunc a dolor posuere dui convallis faucibus quis ut augue. Ut bibendum enim eget mollis eleifend. Ut vitae rutrum mi. Donec mattis eget sapien eget dapibus. Morbi et facilisis elit, nec condimentum eros.

Nulla egestas elit vitae orci bibendum vestibulum. Vivamus id justo lectus. Donec sed porta lorem. Ut egestas nibh ac elit iaculis, eu fringilla lorem faucibus. Phasellus lacus elit, suscipit vel gravida id, placerat vitae diam. Duis dictum tincidunt sem et euismod. Nam vestibulum sem nec elit congue commodo. Pellentesque ultrices vitae eros eu faucibus. Duis enim massa, volutpat eu tellus sed, porttitor aliquam mi. Praesent vel neque sit amet enim fermentum ultrices. Integer blandit mauris sed eros rhoncus auctor. Mauris tempor ante fermentum purus viverra dapibus.

In eleifend auctor semper. Integer sapien ante, tempus a magna vitae, tincidunt vulputate nisi. In pharetra interdum lorem, eu efficitur tellus consequat porta. Morbi eleifend tempor leo. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque ut erat dui. Proin vehicula nunc sit amet lacus ultrices, vel dignissim nisi cursus. In elementum dictum tincidunt. Sed eget augue blandit, accumsan sapien sed, aliquet felis.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since i went lost in your code, i write new, which show how to define headers and footers that they appear on each page. it should be defined in preamble.

my mwe not consider greek language (i anticipate, that this is not difficult to add)

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[margin=1in,top=0.5in,%
                headheight=3\baselineskip,headsep=2\baselineskip,includehead,%
%                showframe
                ]{geometry}
    \usepackage{multirow, tabulary}
    \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{MatlabCellColour}{RGB}{252,251,220}
    \usepackage{lastpage}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\lhead{%
    \begin{tabular}{cl}
\multirow{3}{*}{\includegraphics[width=15mm,height=15mm]{ex_logo.png}}
    & \textcolor{blue}{TEX} \\
    & A great site for \LaTeX enthusiasts\\
    & \href{https://tex.stackexchange.com/}{https://tex.stackexchange.com/},
      \href{mailto:info@tex.stackexchange.com/}{info@tex.stackexchange.com} \\
    & \\
\end{tabular}
        }
\chead{}
\rhead{}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{tex.stackexchange.com}
\rfoot{text \thepage \hspace{1pt} text\ \pageref{LastPage}}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\lipsum\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

top of the first page is the same as at all other pages. is this what you like to obtain. if the first page should have different header/footer, than you need to define separate style for it and include it by `\thispagestyle{<name of style}` after \begin{document}.

Comment: @Minas, my code is only for english language, for greek you need to add babel with all option needed for greek (which i haven't installed) . as is, mwe works (tested). to include suggested solution in your document, just add rest of your document preamble except your definition of page layout. it is in my document (mwe) defined by the package `geometry`. if the layout is not what you like to have, accordingly change only `margin` in `geometry's options, other definitions is defined as needed for your page header.

Comment: Thank you @Zarco, it is working. I had to remove though [demo] from the grapicx package. For Greek I used: \usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\newcommand{\en}{\selectlanguage{english}}
\newcommand{\gr}{\selectlanguage{greek}}.

Comment: @Minas, super! i'm glad that you maged adaption of my suggestion to your document. as i said, unfortunately went lost in your program :-(. happy tex-ing